# Converting a List to a subclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

We have some code that is currently calling a remote EJB which returns a list of `ClassA` objects. I need to add a couple more properties to `ClassA`, but I'm told we don't want to modify the remote EJB at all. So I created a `ClassB` that extends `ClassA` and adds on these new properties. So what I'm stuck on is I can't figure out how to convert my `List<ClassA>` to a `List<ClassB>`.

```
public class ClassA {

    private String propA;
    private String propB;

}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    private String propC;
    private String propD;

}

public class ServiceClass {

    public List<ClassA> getInfo() {
        List<ClassA> myInfo = remoteEjb.serviceCall();
        return myInfo;
    }

}
```

How do I turn `myInfo` into a `List<ClassB>`?

Comment: Will the remote EJB be aware of `ClassB` and create and return instances of that class (wrapped in a `List<ClassA>`)? If not, you'd need to generate (copy) a `ClassB` instance locally from each `ClassA` instance returned from the remote EJB.

Comment: This seems like a bad use of inheritance. Composition sounds much better. Let class B have an attribute of class A and also add the new properties.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert Super Class to Subclass. You can take each property and set in new instance of Class B one by one or use converters like dozer.

SO Answer on that: [Converting Object of SuperClass to Sub Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192402/converting-object-of-superclass-to-sub-class)